# Vuetify Dynamic Binding of Property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've got a form which contains a dynamic set of input components (v-selects and v-text-fields) that a user has to set. However, I'm really struggling to understand how to retrieve the values from these input components once the user submits the form. My input setup looks like this:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col
    v-for="(item, index) in documentTags.tags"
    :key="index"
    cols="18"
    sm="8"
    md="6"
  >
    <v-select
      v-if="item.InputType === 'Combobox'"
      :v-model="documentTagResponses[index]"
      :name="item.Name"
      :items="item.TagValueOptions"
      :rules="rules.ComboboxRule"
      item-text="Value"
      :label="item.Name"
      required
    >
    </v-select>
    <v-text-field
      v-else-if="item.InputType === 'Textbox'"
      :v-model="documentTagResponses[index]"
      :name="item.Name"
      :label="item.Name"
      :rules="rules.TextboxRule"
      required
    >
    </v-text-field>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

And my documentTags definition looks something like this:

```
{
  tags: [
    {
      TagDefinitionId: '1',
      InputType: 'Combobox',
      Name: 'Name_1',
      TagValueOptions: [
        {
          Value: 'Option 1',
        },
        {
          Value: 'Option 2',
        },
        {
          Value: 'Option 3',
        },                
      ],
    },
    {
      TagDefinitionId: '2',
      InputType: 'Textbox',
      Name: 'Name_2',
      TagValueOptions: [],
    },
  ],
}
```

I'm trying to bind the form responses from these inputs to an array called *documentTagResponses*.
So, something like this:

```
export default {
name: 'MyModal',
data: () => ({
    documentTagResponses: [],
}),
methods: {
    validate() {
        const valid = this.$refs.form.validate();
        if (valid) { 
            for (const key of Object.keys(this.documentTagResponses)) {
                console.log(`${key} -> ${this.documentTagResponses[key]}`);
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Then, when the user clicks the *submit* button, I call the *validate* function to ensure the components are valid and then do something with the values... Right now I'm simply trying to print the values of each component to the console. However, my *documentTagResponses* array is always empty. Does anyone know why I can't seem to access the values that are being set in these components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code in my project and the problem was `:v-model`
We don't need `:` in v-model

So the code can be like below

```
<v-row>
  <v-col
    v-for="(item, index) in documentTags.tags"
    :key="index"
    cols="18"
    sm="8"
    md="6"
  >
    <v-select
      v-if="item.InputType === 'Combobox'"
      v-model="documentTagResponses[index]"
      :name="item.Name"
      :items="item.TagValueOptions"
      :rules="rules.ComboboxRule"
      item-text="Value"
      :label="item.Name"
      required
    >
    </v-select>
    <v-text-field
      v-else-if="item.InputType === 'Textbox'"
      v-model="documentTagResponses[index]"
      :name="item.Name"
      :label="item.Name"
      :rules="rules.TextboxRule"
      required
    >
    </v-text-field>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Comment: I understand it is sometimes hard for experienced developers to find that kind of mistake. In that case, bring it to beginners!